# Tunneling DNS traffic with OpenVPN over Hamachi

Tags: dns, routing, tunnel, openvpn, hamachi

Due to some particular requirements that I can't get around, I need to use OpenVPN over a Hamachi network to establish a working VPN connection.  I have a server running Ubuntu that has an instance of Hamachi and an instance of OpenVPN Server running at all times.

In order to connect with OpenVPN, I use the IP address issued to the Hamachi network interface as the host address.  The connection completes perfectly however when I attempt to access or ping a website, the DNS will not resolve.

Within the OpenVPN Server config, I have uncommented the lines that would push OpenDNS server addresses to clients and have even specified the DNS servers in the client config but to no avail.

The kicker is that I used to use OpenVPN without Hamachi (using the public IP) to the same server and the DNS would pass through just fine.

Any suggestions? would bridging the Hamachi interface to the public interface enable DNS lookups to pass through?

Comment: "I need to use OpenVPN over a Hamachi network to establish a working VPN connection." I'm sorry. I'm so sorry.

Comment: That doesn't really help me at all but thank you? Anyways, I wish I didn't need Hamachi as an intermediary but my ISP cuts off OpenVPN at the TLS handshake and changing ports doesn't work.